# How to make radiobutton marked based on dropdown index changed event in mvc 4 entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my view code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.GroupID)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupID, Model.GroupList, "Please select", new { id = "ddlgrp" })
    if (ViewBag.selectedperms!=null)
    { 
        foreach(var permission in Model.Permissions)
        {
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.perm_id,permission.perm_id)
                <span>@permission.perm_levelname</span>
            </label>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var permission in Model.Permissions)
        {
            <label>
                @if (Model.perm_id.Equals(ViewBag.selectedperms))
                {
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.perm_id,permission.perm_id,true)
                    <span>@permission.perm_levelname</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.perm_id,permission.perm_id)
                    <span>@permission.perm_levelname</span>
                }
            </label>
        }  
    }
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
```

This is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlgrp").change(function () {
        $("#log").ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
            alert(exception);
        });
        var grpselected = $("select option:selected").val();
        alert(grpselected);
        $.get('@Url.Action("CheckPermissions")',
            { id: grpselected }, function (data) {
        });
    });
});
```

This is actionmethod

```
public ActionResult CheckPermissions(int id)
{
    tblperm od = new tblperm();
    var selectedperms = (from c in db.tblperm where c.grp_id==id select c.perm_id).SingleOrDefault();
    ViewBag.selectedperms = selectedperms;
    return View(od);
}
```

Assume for groupip id 1 there is a permisson with permid 1. So when i select 1 from dropdwon corresponding dropdown with id 1 should be checked. I have tried with above code but its not working. Can anybody suggest me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Anybody who can help me here?

Comment: Provide some sort of clear code & what exactly you are trying to do to get help.

Comment: I want to make radiobutton checked based on dropdown. dropdown contains group ids. For groupid 1 there is a permission id 1. So when i select 1 in dropdown permission id with 1(radiobutton) should be checked. Viewbag.selecetedperms contains corresponding permission id. Now i want to bring viewbag data to view and based to viewbag data i want to make radiobutton true

Comment: return view(od ) maybe here i am going wrong because view is not getting called again

Comment: Let me know if you have any doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like following snippet.

```js
$("#GroupID").change(function () {
    $('input[name="perm_id"][value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="GroupID">
    <option value="">Select group</option>
    <option value="1">Group 1</option>
    <option value="2">Group 2</option>
    <option value="3">Group 3</option>
    <option value="4">Group 4</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" value="1" name="perm_id" /><label>Permission 1</label>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="perm_id" /><label>Permission 2</label>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="perm_id" /><label>Permission 3</label>
<input type="radio" value="4" name="perm_id" /><label>Permission 4</label>
```

**Update**

**Action method**

```
public ActionResult CheckPermissions(int id)
{
    tblperm od = new tblperm();
    var selectedperms = (from c in db.tblperm where c.grp_id == id select c.perm_id).SingleOrDefault();

    return Json(selectedperms, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#ddlgrp").change(function () {        
    var grpselected = $(this).val();

    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("CheckPermissions")', { id: grpselected }, function (data) {
        $('input[name="perm_id"][value="' + data + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Correct Yes this is what i need. but i want to get radiobutton value from db. In my action method ViewBag.selectedperms get value from db. now i want this value in view. I dont know how to send it to view

Comment: In the above example this.value which is nothing but viewbag.selectedperms. Hope you clearly understood

Comment: i want to know how to send viewbag with the help of model to the view? because viewbag will have value only after dropdown changes?

Comment: Yes it is working but without json i am trying. I want to send selectedperms to view without jquery somthing i need less usage of jquery,json. Is this possible to achieve without jquery?

Comment: In the way you are trying. The answer is no. @KiranKumar

Comment: oh okay. How can i send viewbag.selectedperms to view?

Comment: `ViewBag` can pass data from controller action to corresponding view, not other view. @KiranKumar

Comment: Okay how to send it to same view? and in above query if data conatisn two dimension integer(if there is two checkboxes for read and write ) then how to sove this?

Comment: This is too large to answer. You should load all data when the page is loading from server. Do  some R&D for it. @KiranKumar